# Probate vs Non-Probate Assets for Wills

Tags: united-states, new-york-state, wills, trusts-and-estates, probate

New York State (USA) here. I'm having trouble understanding the difference between **Probate** and **Non-Probate** assets, from a Will/Testament standpoint.

I *believe* non-probate assets are specific gifts you call out -- in the Will -- that are designated for specific beneficiaries. Little Jimmy gets the old pair of lucky Yankees socks, Little Suzie gets the old, decrepit, half-eaten turkey sandwich that Babe Ruth once took a bite out of, etc.

I *believe* probate assets are simply anything you (the Deceased; the Testator) owns prior to death that is not specifically called out as a non-probate asset and designated to a specific beneficiary.

If that's right, then I'm guessing things like:

- 401ks/Roth IRAs
- Life Insurance policies
- Savings accounts
- Stock market investments
- Houses, land & real property

...could all be probate assets if one does't specifically gift them to a Beneficiary?

And if my understanding is incorrect, then I could use some course correction and steering here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are wrong again. I'll answer when I have a chance.

Comment: Oh perfect! These kinds of misunderstandings are exactly what Q&A sites like Law.SE are set up for!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I believe non-probate assets are specific gifts you call out -- in the
> Will -- that are designated for specific beneficiaries. Little Jimmy
> gets the old pair of lucky Yankees socks, Little Suzie gets the old,
> decrepit, half-eaten turkey sandwich that Babe Ruth once took a bite
> out of, etc.

This is incorrect. Every transfer arising from a will is a probate asset, because probate is the formal legal process of determining if there was a will, and if so, which will applies, and then distributing  the assets of the person who died in accordance with that will (or with the determination that there was no will).

> I'm guessing things like:
>
> 401ks/Roth IRAs
>
> Life Insurance policies
>
> Savings accounts
>
> Stock market
>
> investments
>
> Houses, land & real property ...could all be probate assets if one
> does't specifically gift them to a Beneficiary?

A 401k/Roth IRA with a beneficiary designation (other than the owner's estate), a life insurance policy with a beneficiary designation (other than the owner's estate), a savings account or stock account or investment with a joint owner or a pay on death beneficiary (other than the owner's estate), or real property with a transfer on death beneficiary or a joint ownership with right of survivorship is a non-probate asset.

Any of those assets if there is no beneficiary designation, if there is no pay on death beneficiary, if there is no joint owner with right of survivorship, if it is not owner through a trust, and if there is a beneficiary designation that names the owner's estate, is a probate asset.

**The General Rule**

Anything subject to allocation and distribution in a will, or by intestate succession is a probate asset. Specifically devised property in a will is a probate asset.

A non-probate assets is something transferred pursuant to a beneficiary designation, pay on death provision, joint ownership with right of survivorship, tenancy by entireties, or provision in a trust existing prior to the death of the decedent. These assets are not dealt with through the probate court process.

However, if a will purports to specifically devise property that has a beneficiary designation or pay on death beneficiary or is owned by a trust or is in joint tenancy with right of survivorship, then the non-probate transfer prevails over the inconsistent language in the will.

See also:

> Examples of Non-Probate Transfers Used in Estate Planning
>
> The following are examples of non-probate transfers commonly used in
> estate planning:
>
> 1. Passing property to beneficiaries through a living trust.
> 2. Leaving funds to a beneficiary named on a pay on death account or transfer on death account.
> 3. Leaving funds to a beneficiary named on a life insurance policy.
> 4. Leaving funds to a beneficiary named on an IRA, 401k or other retirement account. See financial planning.
> 5. Holding title to property as joint tenants or tenancy by the entirety.
> 6. Leaving motor vehicles to a transfer on death beneficiary.
> 7. Gifting assets to heirs during your lifetime so the assets do not pass as part of your estate.
> 8. Executing and recording a transfer on death deed naming a beneficiary to inherit your real estate.

([Source](https://pennyborn.com/nonprobatetransfers.html))

The American Bar Association devotes [a full chapter length treatment](https://www.americanbar.org/content/dam/aba-cms-dotorg/products/inv/book/402582144/chap_1_excerpt_5130245.pdf) to discussing the difference. It begins:

> Upon death, a decedent’s estate includes both probate and nonprobate
> assets. Probate assets are those that pass to persons identified in a
> will (see Chapter 3 for a discussion of wills), whereas nonprobate
> assets pass outside an estate’s administration. Examples of
> traditional nonprobate assets include qualified and nonqualified
> retirement plans, individual retirement accounts, and life insurance
> policies. However, nonprobate assets can also include certain checking
> and savings accounts, certificates of deposit, investments, and even
> real property, but only if a beneficiary is designated and state law
> allows for such an asset to pass outside of an estate’s
> administration. Nonprobate assets are frequently referred to as “will
> substitutes.”

Comment: Hi @ohwilleke, last followup question about probate vs non-probate (I promise), if you don't mind. I now understand that anything that is not jointly-owned (with rights of survivorship), is not an asset with a designated beneficiary (life insurance policy with named beneficiary, etc.), and is not owned by a trust is a probate asset. If that old pair of Yankees socks is mentioned in the Will to go to, say, my son, its a probate asset; but does it have a special name/classification since its a probate asset _mentioned_ in the Will with a named beneficiary? Thanks again!

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup In modern terminology, a direction in a will to give a specific thing to a specific person is called a "specific devise". Directions to give things (not necessary specific) to a person in a will are called "devises and bequests". Historically, devises were transfers of real property via a will, and bequests were transfers of property that is not real property via a will, but these terms are now often used without that distinction.

Comment: IIUC, this is federal law, hence preempts state law, but for stuff not defined by federal law, do state laws on probate differ much?

Comment: @smci This is almost entirely state law (federal tax law influences how trusts and wills are designed by the probate v. non-probate distinction isn't very important there). State laws for probate administration differ greatly from each other. State laws for the substantive law of wills, trusts, and non-probate transfers differ moderately in a few areas (e.g. revocation of non-probate transfers by operation of law upon a divorce, nuncupative wills and holographic wills). NYS is moderately atypical compared to the majority rules nationally.

Comment: @ohwilleke: Uhuh. If the decedent lived in state A, their ex-spouse in state B, the beneficiaries in states C,D,E and the property was in states F,G, which state's probate laws are used?

Comment: @smci The decedents domicile controls, unless there is a choice of law clause in the contract. However, domicile also does not apply if ERISA or certain federal benefits like FEGLI life insurance benefits are involved. In those cases, federal common law applies.

Answer (score 3):

You could read [this page](https://www.antonelli-legal.com/blog/probate-assets-vs-non-probate-assets.cfm). The main point is that probate assets are those owned individually by the decedent, and do not have a survivorship right or named beneficiary. Non-probate assets are those with rights of survivorship or a beneficiary designation. Examples of the latter: multiple individuals as joint tenants with rights of survivorship, or held as tenants by the entirety; joint bank accounts; life insurance or retirement benefits with a named beneficiary; property held in the name of a trust. Retirement benefits, bank accounts, real property etc. can also be a probate estate.

Comment: Thanks @user6726 (+1) -- so just to confirm, something is a "_probate asset_" if its not crystal clear who should own it after the decedent...dies, yes? Is there an overlap between "probate assets" and what I see referred to as "residue" (everything thats left over to be liquidated for an estate)? Because I'm now starting to lean towards thinking of probate assets and residue as one in the same (?). Thanks again!

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup " if its not crystal clear who should own it after the decedent...dies," No. "I'm now starting to lean towards thinking of probate assets and residue as one in the same" Also no. Specifically devised property in a will is a probate asset.

Comment: Whats the definition of "_devised property_" then? Google says its "a gift of real property made in a will", which sounds like...a non-probate asset.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup Will=probate. Gifts made in a will are, by definition, probate assets. That's what probate assets means (except that it has also come to mean gifts made by intestacy laws since that involves the same court process). Literally, in the narrow sense, "probate" means to recognize a will as valid.

Comment: "devised property" is property left in a will to a specific person, entity, or group. It need not be real property. aNY  "devised property" is a probate asset. Anything governed by a will is a probate asset.

Comment: Truly not trying to be difficult, but I'm seeing completely conflicting definitions in these answers. On one hand @ohwilleke you say that gifts made in a will are probate assets. On the other hand you also say that a non-probate asset is something transferred pursuant to a beneficiary designation. Both of these sound identical to me, yet one is described as probate and the other, non-probate. If I leave an old pair of socks to my son in my will, this is a non-probate asset, yes? But then it seems its also devised property, or left in a will to a specific person and so its also probate asset??

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup "a non-probate asset is something transferred pursuant to a beneficiary designation" A "beneficiary designation" means a statement about who gets something at death that is not part of a will, usually but not always in a contract setting up a financial investment. "If I leave an old pair of socks to my son, this is a non-probate asset, yes?" No.

Comment: Ahhh, apologies. I had a mental hangup (for some reason) that non-probate assets had to be mentioned as part of the will. [This diagram](https://www.niehauslaw.com/articles-newsletters/probate-vs-non-probate-assets) seems to sum it up nicely, for the laymen.