# Death of seller in residential home sale - is probate required? (Florida, USA)

Tags: real-estate, florida, homeownership

I have a purchase and sale agreement to buy a house in the Orlando, FL area, with a scheduled closing date of 5/1/2023. Unfortunately, the seller passed away last week, leaving the house to her son in her will.

The listing agent is saying that the sale must go into probate, and has started the process. My mortgage broker checked with the title people he works with, and they're saying that as long as the will is clear and uncontested, probate is not necessary in this situation. As far as I know the will isn't being contested; I'm sure the listing agent would have communicated that if it were the case. And obviously I don't know whether the will is otherwise ok, but again I haven't heard otherwise.

The listing agent isn't giving any reason why they think this must go into probate, and I have the feeling that they're on autopilot, assuming that death = probate. Unfortunately our agent is completely out of her depth here, and unwilling to push back on them on anything. She just accepts whatever they say. The delay of probate will have HUGE consequences for us, both financial and personal.

I don't know if this is enough information to answer this question -- but is probate always required in a situation like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probate vs Non-Probate Assets for Wills](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/84818/probate-vs-non-probate-assets-for-wills)

Comment: Thanks @Sneftel. It gives me a good idea of the probate process overall, though it's specific to NY State.

Comment: You are very close to being closed as a duplicate / asking for legal advice (which is off-topic here) (2 votes for each reason).  Personally, I don't think the suggested duplicate is - but you could certainly reduce the "asking for legal advice" risk by [edit]ing the question to make it general, rather than your specific case (but do include the jurisdiction).

Comment: This question is NOT asking for legal advice, it is asking about Florida law as it applies to real estate sales and probate.  Having gone through this recently I know WA law says probate is required if the decedent has real estate assets.  The question is clear, and Florida law should be similarly clear on this matter.  The question is answerable, the close votes are unwarranted.

Comment: I'm baffled that anyone would interpret this as asking for legal advice. The question is, "Is probate always required in a situation like this?" Where is the request for legal advice?

Comment: And a duplicate was suggested, which was a good overview of probate in NY, much of which may or may not also apply elsewhere. But I'm asking about FL law, so information about another state, while it may be helpful in general, can't be an answer. (And I did include the jurisdiction, because I know that.) I gave a brief synopsis of my situation for context, to explain where the question comes from, but "what should I do?" is neither expressed nor implied, as they say.

Comment: @MichaelHall If it wasn't asking for legal advice, it could be asked in 1 sentence, and wouldn't use the phrase "I", give a specific Florida city, the opinion of a specific real estate agent, and specific dates.

Comment: @user71659 So even _I_ am mistaken in thinking that I'm not asking for legal advice?

Comment: @user71659, that's just background info for context, to make the question a bit more interesting and relatable...  it doesn't change the fundamental question: "What does the law say about it?" If situational detail in the question is what pushes things into the category of legal advice we'd have to close an awful lot of questions on this site.

Comment: Well, the naysayers have it. The question is closed as "off topic." A question about what the law says. Who'd a thunk it?

Comment: @CraigM The naysayers are right. As phrased, this is a request for legal advice - it is specific to a particular case. It can easily be generalized to focus on the overall concepts rather than a specific contract with a specific closing date. Do that and we can reopen.

Comment: I have updated an answer at https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/91328/what-does-florida-state-law-say-regarding-probate-in-real-estate-transactions which may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the owner of real estate can sign the paperwork transferring title from A to B. The titular owner is now dead, so there is a process whereby some other person is authorized to dispose of the decedents property – the personal representative could do this. There is a prior procedure procedure whereby that individual is appointed to be the decedent's personal representative. Since Florida does not have Transfer on Death deeds, the property cannot pass immediately to the son.

In is not inconceivable that the PR can be appointed within a month, but the 90 day creditor claims deadline is a hard legal fact. This might not matter if the house has the Florida homestead exemption, and might not matter if it doesn't, but ask your lawyer.

Comment: The creditor claim deadline is a bar to distribution of the proceeds, but not to the closing itself. It just means that the net proceeds must be retained in the estate until creditor's claims are disposed of.